# Why did Vali join the Chaos Brigade?

Tags: high-school-dxd

Exactly as the title says. Why? As of volume 16 of the light novel, the leader of the Chaos Brigade is Rizevim Livan Lucifer, his grandfather. His grandfather killed Vali's father and was the man behind the bad treatment his parents gave him during his childhood ([Rizevim Livan Lucifer](http://highschooldxd.wikia.com/wiki/Rizevim_Livan_Lucifer) & [Vali Lucifer](http://highschooldxd.wikia.com/wiki/Vali_Lucifer)). So why did he join the Chaos Brigade in the first place? Why did he betray Azazel and the Grigori who raised him after he fled from home?

Comment: Vali Lucifer was in the Vali Team, a special team of the Khaos Brigade led by Vali himself. The Vali Team was not connected to any of the factions of the Khaos Brigade and acted independently. So he maybe have joined to get connection inside the faction. or to gather as much power for his revenge.